# Postgresql bulk collect

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, bulkinsert

Im trying to migrate oracle app to postgresql.
In one of the oracle`s functions i have the next code :

```
    V_Step := 3;
command := 'declare
      type tab_data is table of ' || tab_name ||
           '%ROWTYPE;

     CURSOR raw_data is SELECT * FROM ' || tab_name ||
           '_vw;
      mydata tab_data;
      V_COUNTER  integer := 0;
      BEGIN
      open raw_data;
      LOOP
        V_COUNTER := V_COUNTER + 1;
        FETCH raw_data BULK COLLECT INTO mydata LIMIT ' ||
           to_char(current_setting('Gaps.BATCH_SIZE')::bigint) || ';
        FORALL i IN 1..mydata.COUNT
             INSERT  INTO ' || tab_name ||
           ' VALUES mydata(i);

        EXIT WHEN raw_data%NOTFOUND;
      END LOOP;
      RAISE NOTICE ''V_COUNTER = '%', V_COUNTER;
      --commit;
      close raw_data;
      END;';
V_Step := 4;

   RAISE NOTICE '%', command;

V_Step := 5;
EXECUTE command;
```

We are trying to load into a local postgresql table huge amount of data from remote oracle table (I have link). In oracle using bulk make it faster than regular `insert into x select * from`. Is there any function in postgresql that is similar to oracle`s bulk ?

Comment: you could use an array of the table type: `tab_data tab_name[]` and use `array_agg()` in the select statement. But I would first try with a plain `insert ... select ... from link_table` doing "batched" inserts should only be necessary for billions of rows. Anything in the "millions" should work just fine.

Comment: OK, thanks. I will post again if I`ll have performance issues.